# Сформатировать время -- секунды в строку: hh:mm:ss часы, минуты, секунды

Tags: python, python-3.x, время, таймер

Вообщем у меня есть бредовый код который я пытался сделать:

```
def secondsToStr(self, t):
    return "%d:%02d:%02d.%03d" % \
        reduce(lambda ll,b : divmod(ll[0],b) + ll[1:],
            [(t*1000,),1000,60,60])
```

Что мне нужно? Что бы на выходе у меня было время до окончания. У меня есть переменная `self.lototimer = time.time()`

Как из не высчитывать секунды я понял:

```
3600 - round(time.time() - self.lototimer
```

Как мне сделать теперь что бы на выходе мне выдало время до окончания вот такое

> hh:mm:ss часы, минуты, секунды.
>
> Пример: до окончания лотереи 01:59:51

Comment: связанный вопрос [How to convert seconds to hours, minutes and seconds?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/775049/4279), [python: format time elapsed from seconds to hour, mins and sceconds](https://stackoverflow.com/q/27779677/4279)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вроде бы, у вас `t` это секунды, тогда:

```
def seconds_to_str(seconds: int) -> str:
    mm, ss = divmod(seconds, 60)
    hh, mm = divmod(mm, 60)
    return "%02d:%02d:%02d" % (hh, mm, ss)

print(seconds_to_str(1))     # 00:00:01
print(seconds_to_str(60))    # 00:01:00
print(seconds_to_str(3600))  # 01:00:00
print(seconds_to_str(3678))  # 01:01:18
print(seconds_to_str(8888))  # 02:28:08
```

Comment: `str(timedelta(seconds=seconds))` может быть проще

Comment: @jfs, думал об этом, но там формат времени `h`, а не `hh`: `print(str(timedelta(seconds=5)))  # 0:00:05`, да и если времени больше чем сутки, то часы переведутся в дни и формат будет отличаться от того что в вопросе

Comment: Очень сильно благодарен вам. Успехов вам!