# Как конвертировать время в формат чч:мм?

Tags: python, datetime

```
import datetime as dt

my_datetime = dt.datetime(2023, 3, 28, 00, 00, 00)
m_datetime = dt.datetime.now()
v = m_datetime - my_datetime
print("С начала текущих суток прошло:", v)
```

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Сформатировать время -- секунды в строку: hh:mm:ss часы, минуты, секунды](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/865954/); [Найти промежуток времени от одной отметки до другой. Python](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1477679/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если вам нужно просто вывести текущее время (это то же самое, что время прошедшее с начала суток), то вообще вычитать не нужно ничего.

Нужно просто `dt.datetime.now()` отформатировать с форматом `%H:%M`:

```
import datetime as dt

now = dt.datetime.now()
print(f"С начала текущих суток прошло: {now:%H:%M}")
```

Если нужно получить именно из `v` (`timedelta`), то берете из `v` полное количество секунд, делите нацело с остатком (`divmod`) на 3600 - частное будет количеством часов. Остаток делите на 60 - получаете количество минут:

```
import datetime as dt

my_datetime = dt.datetime(2023, 3, 28, 00, 00, 00)
m_datetime = dt.datetime.now()
v = m_datetime - my_datetime
hours, seconds = divmod(int(v.total_seconds()), 3600)
minutes = seconds // 60
# Если нужны будут секунды, то вместо просто деления на 60 делайте опять divmod:
# minutes, seconds = divmod(seconds, 60)
print(f"С начала текущих суток прошло: {hours:02}:{minutes:02}")
```

Comment: Огромное спасибо